# saving data from two columns into two lists

Tags: python, list, numpy, math, split

I have two columns with float numbers. What I need is to seperate data in each column into seperate lists(x and y) and plot the data y vs x. I wrote something but it keeps giving me an error which is,
*ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack*

extract of the data file looks as below,

```
0.0 1.0   
0.02 1.0   
0.04 1.0  
0.06 1.0  
0.08 1.0   
0.1 1.0   
0.12 1.0   
0.14 1.0   
0.16 1.0   
0.18 1.0   
0.2 1.0  
0.22 1.0   
0.24 1.0   
0.26 1.0   
0.28 1.0   
0.3 1.0
```

and my code looks like this,

```
  import NumPy as np
  import math

  f = open('partA-imag.dat' , "r").  
  lines = f.readlines(). 
  #file.close().                                                                       
  x_axis = [].                                                                       
  y_axis = [].                                                                       
  for line in lines: 
      x,y = line.split(). 
      x_axis.append(x). 
      y_axis.append(y). 
      print(x,y). 

  print(x_axis). 
  print(y_axis). 
  plt.plot(x_axis,y_axis). 
  plt.show()
```

Comment: try `lines = f.read()`

Comment: nope, didn't work

Comment: can you show exactly what the data in the file looks like? Try `x, y = line.split(' ')`

Comment: that still gives me the same error.

Comment: I updated the extracted data to make it more clear. extracted data here are from top to some point and all the other lines look exactly the same.

Comment: Did you pay attention as to where the error occurred?  The error message should have indicated exactly which line.  You should have shown that to us as well!  We guessed it was the `x,y=...` line because that's the only spot where you are doing `unpacking`, but we shouldn't to guess.  Further more you should have looked at what `line.split()` does.  Does it produce 2 values or not?  For all lines?

Comment: I am so new to python and I thought line.split() command should split the two data in a line which is sperated by a space.

Answer (score 0):

```
lines = f.readlines()
x_ = []
y_ = []
for line in lines:
    x, y = line.split(' ')
    x_.append(float(x.rstrip()))
    y_.append(float(y.rstrip()))
```

Comment: gives me this error
"y_.append(float(y.rstrip())). 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "

Comment: this means an empty line came, check for empty lines

Comment: honestly there aren't any empty lines in either of the columns

Comment: I wish there's a way to share the data file to you so you can see it too!

Comment: @Xdrake I managed to do this with your file by changing this line `x, y = line.split()`